# Is a vulnerability identified in Python considered a vulnerability in Jython?

Tags: python, security, jython, cpython

A lil confused as the diffs between Python, Jython and CPython.
I understand Jython is an implementation of Python in Java and CPython is the same except that it is implemented in C.

But what I'm confused on really is identifying vulnerabilities in Python.
Such as the two below.

For example - CVE-2016-5636 - Here it appears that the vulnerability can't be reproduced in Jython.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1345857

Similarly looking at - CVE-2016-5699
https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-5699

It says
"CRLF injection vulnerability in the HTTPConnection.putheader function in urllib2 and urllib in **CPython** (aka Python) before 2.7.10 and 3.x before 3.4.4 allows remote attackers to inject arbitrary HTTP headers via CRLF sequences in a URL."

Does this mean CVE-2016-5699 is not vulnerable in Jython?

So overall- What I'm wondering is if a vulnerability in Python means it is vulnerable in Jython?

Comment: I'm not confident in my knowledge enough of the topic, but this would likely be entirely dependent on how the exploit worked. Additional checks may occur when instructions are compiled to java bytecode, and implementation specific bugs (read: effectively typos) will likely not be continued across interpreters unless the source is the same.. that said, it would be easy to inadvertently carry over semantic errors in code when translating from one language to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. When you refer to such things as "Python", you are potentially referring to two different things:

- The Python language
- The Python virtual machine (VM) or other specific implementation

Normally the Python language doesn't change (much) across different implementations. What changes is how the language is processed, including what external system functions are called.

Python without any other distinction would normally refer to CPython, the standard implementation. Others, as you mention above, are Jython and IronPython. Each of these runs in a different VM: JVM for Jython and dotnet for IronPython. These VMs might, for example, allocate memory differently thus preventing a memory-based error from occurring in a different VM. In the case of CVE-2016-5636 mentioned, it's noted that Jython calls the Java version of zip, while CPython likely calls the C version of zip.

In short - if the flaw occurs in how the language approaches a problem, it's likely to affect all implementations. Otherwise, you will need to check each platform's vulnerability on an individual basis.

Addendum: According [the Red Hat tracker for CVE-2016-5699](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=CVE-2016-5699), this is language error and therefore is likely (but not guaranteed) to be vulnerable in all implementations until updated.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, it all depends which parts of Python standard lib JPython uses, which are modified, which are re-implemented, which are omitted...

`urllib` is a part of standard Python distribution, and you can find `urllib.py` in `Lib` folder of both, standard CPython and JPython. Sadly, they even state it in their code:

```
__version__ = '1.17'    # XXX This version is not always updated :-(
```

So you cannot rely on that to figure out if the Python code itself is at fault (and is it fixed in a specific version).

Also, the exploit doesn't have to be necessary related to the actual Python wrapping around the lower level bytecode and ultimately the interpreter - it can be in any of those things, or combination of them. That's why they say that the exploit doesn't exist in a particular CPython version as it is assumed that the whole stack, together with the standard lib, is updated.

So, unless the exploit specifically says that the problem is in the Python code itself (e.g. in `urllib.py` in your example) and that it is fixed in a specific version of the said module, you cannot be sure that it's not due to the underlying interpreter, and if it is - whether the same applies for both PVM and JVM.